# Quantum Ising model phase transitions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, statistical-mechanics, phase-transition, ising-model

In the classical Ising model, there are multiple ways to tackle questions regarding the existence of phase transitions. One way would be to look at spontaneous symmetry breaking of the order parameter (i.e. magnetization in this case), but the (more formal) definition I'm familiar with is the non-analyticity of the free energy (in the thermodynamic limit).
In the classical case, it's easy to see that the free energy is analytic at a temperature T if the partition function is non-zero in a neighbour of T.

However, it is not clear to me if this is also the case for the Quantum Ising model.

For example, if I consider the hamiltonian
$$
H = - \sum_{\langle i, j \rangle} \sigma_z^i \sigma_z^j - h\sum_i \sigma_x^i,
$$
with partition function
$$
Z = Tr(e^{-\beta H}),
$$
it seems to me that the free energy is still well-defined, simply as
$$ 
F = - T\ln[Z].
$$

**Question 1.** Does it still make sense to talk about quantum phase transitions in terms of non-analyticity of $F$ (either in the temperature parameter, or in the transverse field parameter).

**Question 2.** If so, and I do find a non analytic point, how do I know which order parameter is relevant? In the classical case, the apparent parameter to consider would be magnetization. Since the quantum hamiltonian is a bit more complicated, I wouldn't know why a non-analyticity of $F$ would mean that $\langle \sigma_z^i \rangle$  shows symmetry breaking for example.

Thank you, and I hope my questions kinda make sense. If something is unclear, I can always  modify my questions.

Comment: The free Energy (as well as the partition function) is analytic at *finite size* both in the classical and quantum case. So to define phase transitions in this way it is imperative that we take the thermodynamic limit. It is then a theorem that symmetry breaking implies a non analytic free energy (of a certain free energy). The converse is not true. There are phase transitions which are not given by symmetry breaking

Comment: Okay thank you. But suppose you find non-analyticity, is there a way to know if it corresponds to a specific order parameter?

Comment: Are you asking in general or for the Ising model in transverse field? In any case, spontaneous symmetry breaking in some cases is known to be equivalent to off-diagonal long range order. So the answer to your question is yes, you should then look for ODLRO. The details however are important.